# Difference between Dynamic DynamoDB and DynamoDB auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

AWS recently announced a new feature [Auto Scaling for Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/) with which you can automate capacity management for your tables and global secondary indexes.

How is this new feature different from existing [Dynamic DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scale-dynamodb-with-dynamic-dynamodb/) which was catering to the same needs

Comment: Sorry but i differ with your opinion.          Dynamic dyamodb is a version of dynamodb not managed by aws. Existing scenario before auto scaling came was managed aws service as well but without autoscaling. If you wanted more than 5 read / writes for global secondary indexes then you had to contact aws support. Hence scale out was manual.. Now with auto scaling it has bceome a truly aws managed service.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is: Its fully managed by AWS you dont need to think about setting up/maintain an EC2-Instance. The work behind the scenes is similar.

Comment: So is there still a use case for Dynamic Dynamo DB

Comment: In my point of view: No.
The only reason why Dynamic Dynamo DB exists is because AWS doesnt provide (Auto)Scaling for the DynamoDB Service in the past.